# vue 2.6 custom defineComponent not working

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

```
function defineComponent(options: ComponentOptions<Vue>) {
  Vue.extend(options)
}

defineComponent({
  data(){
    return {
      a:1
    }
  },
  methods:{
    hello(){
      return this.a
    }
  }
})
```

Running the above code results in an error saying that 'this.a' does not exist.

how to fix

Comment: no errors, please provide your entire sample